# Laravel fetch value from another source

Tags: laravel, laravel-form

In PHP I use following code to fetch value from another source

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?=$_REQUEST['HOOK_URL'];?>"
```

How can I do this in Laravel form?

Thanks

Comment: In laravel you can do that on your controller and pass it to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been sorted. I have used this:

```
<form id="form" name="frmbasket" action="SAPEVENT:POST" method="post">
```